# HTML BACKGROUND IMAGE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bom dia meu site está quase do jeito que eu gostaria, só tenho um problema com imagem. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] A imagem está dessa forma cortando o teclado e o ombro e eu gostaria que ficasse assim : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 [Link download imagem original](https://ibb.co/bbXrMPQ)

Tentei mudar atributos e até a dimensão da imagem mas não obtive sucesso.
Vou deixar aqui meu código e não reparem que sou leigo em HTML e CSS.
Desde já agradeço.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head> <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Tecnologia de Informação</title>
 </head>    
    <body >

          <div class="container-fluid" id ="c1">

               <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                     <img src="../Site/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                    <h3>
                      <strong class="txtBranco">Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação:</strong>
                    </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">       

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
           </div>

           <body >


     <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3> A Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação (FIT), subordinada á Diretoria Financeira (DFI), é a unidade responsável pela gestão dos sistemas corporativos de informação da Aperam South America.</h3>
              </div>
          </div>

     <div class="col-md-12" >
                  <div class="btn-btn-group"> 
                     <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/229/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infra" id="infraestrutura">Infraestrutura
                         </div> 
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="http://www.de-seguranca.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cloud-computing-600x350.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#segu" id="Segurança">Segurança

                          </div>      
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#siste" id="Sistemas">Sistemas
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tele" id="Telefonia">Telefonia
                          </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>

<!-- Modal Infraestrutura-->
<div class="modal fade" id="infra" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infraLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Infraestrutura</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Componentes ou Plataformas</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Hardware:</strong>
  <font color="black">Consiste na tecnologia para processamento computacional, armazenamento, entrada e saída de dados. Inclui, tambémm, equipamentos para reunir e registrar dados, meios físicos para armazena-los e os dispositivos de saída da informação processada.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Software:</strong>
  <font color="black">É dividido em softwares de sistema e de aplicativos. Os de sistema administram os recursos e as atividades do computador. Os de aplicativos direcionam o computador a uma tarefa específica solicitada pelo usuário.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Rede:</strong>
  <font color="black">Proporciona conectividade de dados entre funcionários, clientes e fornecedores. Isso inclui a tecnologia para operar as redes internas da organização, os serviços prestados por companhias telefônicas ou de telecomunicações e a tecnologia para operar sites e conectar-se com outros sistemas computacionais por meio da internet.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Serviços:</strong>
  <font color="black">As organizações precisam de pessoas para operar e gerenciar os outros componentes da infraestrutura de TI, além de ensinar seus funcionários a usar essas tecnologias em suas atividades. Nem mesmo as grandes organizações tem a equipe, o orçamento ou a experiência requerida para implantar e operar a ampla gama de tecnologias que necessitam. Quando precisam fazer alterações profundas em seus sistemas, ou implantar uma estrutura completamente nova, em geral, as organizações recorrem a consultores externos que as ajudam com a integração do sistema. Existem milhares de fornecedores de tecnologias que oferecem serviços e componentes da infraestrutura de TI, assim como um número igualmente grande de maneiras de combina-los.</font>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
<!-- Modal Segurança-->
<div class="modal fade" id="segu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="segurancaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Segurança</p></h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Pilares da Segurança da Informação</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Confidencialidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Procedimentos e políticas que garantem as restrições do acesso a informações sensíveis aos negócios para estarem disponíveis somente para pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Integridade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Métodos que visam identifica se as informações não sofreram alterações durante o seu processamento ou envio.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Disponibilidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Revisão do acesso á informação para garantir que estejam acessiveis sepre que solicitado por pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:#fff;" > - Autenticidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">É a garantia de que a informação veio da fonte anunciada, de modo que seja possível confirmar sua autoria e originalidade.</font><br><br>
  <font color="black">A famosa frase <strong>"Se algo não pode ser feito com segurançaa, que não seja feito"</strong> também se aplica a Tecnologia ainda mais quando se trata da segurança de nossas informações que caindo em mãos erradas podem trazer prejuizos financeiros e até mesmo acidentes causados por ataques HACKERS como foi o caso  recente da explosão do forno de uma indústria Alemâ que segue nosso mesmo segmento.</font>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Sistemas-->
<div class="modal fade" id="siste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sistemasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Sistemas</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Telefonia-->
<div class="modal fade" id="tele" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="telefoniaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Telefonia</p></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h6  class="text-secondary">    A FITI, Gerência de Infra-estrutura de TI e Telefonia, área ligada á FIT (Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação), é responsável pela gestão da telefonia no âmbito da Aperam Inox América do Sul S.A.
          Sua atuação engloba a gestão da infra-estrutura de telefonia interna (atualização, manutenção, suporte, etc.), a manutenção da malha telefônica, a manutenção das infra-estruturas de video-conferência, a gestão dos contratos de provimento de serviços de telefonia fixa, móvel e video-conferência, o processamento (recebimento, conferência, pagamento, rateio, etc.) das contas telefônicas, o reparo e suporte a aparelhos telefônicos, o estudo de novas tecnologias e a gestão dos projetos afins.</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </body>  

    <!-- Imagem de fundo e LOGO -->
     <style>

          #c1{
         height: 20px;
         background-image: url("ruan.jpg");
         background-size:cover;
         width:100%;
         height:100vh;
         }

          #c1 img {
          max-width:200px;
          max-height:150px;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
         }

         .txtBranco{
           color: #fff;
         }

</style>

 </html>
```

Comment: Cara coloca essa imagem disponível para download em algum lugar. Sem a sua imagem original não da para simular o seu problema...

Comment: Link adicionado ! Obrigado por me informar.

Answer (score 1):

Vc usou o `background-size` como `cover`, por isso cortou a imagem. Se vc quer que a imagem fique inteira na tela vc tem que trocar o cover por `contain`, e centralizar na div com background-position

Sobre o `cover` e o `contain` vc pode entender melhor lendo aqui : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o seu código aplicando esse CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<!-- Imagem de fundo e LOGO -->
<style>
    #c1 {
        /* height: 20px; */
        background-image: url("ruan.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #c1 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 150px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    .txtBranco {
        color: #fff;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="container-fluid" id="c1">

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                    <img src="../Site/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                    <h3>
                        <strong class="txtBranco">Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação:</strong>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <body>


        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3> A Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação (FIT), subordinada á Diretoria Financeira (DFI), é a unidade responsável pela gestão dos sistemas corporativos de informação da Aperam South America.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-btn-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/229/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infra" id="infraestrutura">Infraestrutura
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="http://www.de-seguranca.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cloud-computing-600x350.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#segu" id="Segurança">Segurança

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#siste" id="Sistemas">Sistemas
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/600/350" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tele" id="Telefonia">Telefonia
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Infraestrutura-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="infra" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infraLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                            <p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Infraestrutura</p>
                        </h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4 class="text-primary" style="text-align:center;">
                            <p>Componentes ou Plataformas</p>
                        </h4>
                        <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Hardware:</strong>
                        <font color="black">Consiste na tecnologia para processamento computacional, armazenamento, entrada e saída de dados. Inclui, tambémm, equipamentos para reunir e registrar dados, meios físicos para armazena-los e os dispositivos de saída da informação processada.</font><br>
                        <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Software:</strong>
                        <font color="black">É dividido em softwares de sistema e de aplicativos. Os de sistema administram os recursos e as atividades do computador. Os de aplicativos direcionam o computador a uma tarefa específica solicitada pelo usuário.</font><br>
                        <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Rede:</strong>
                        <font color="black">Proporciona conectividade de dados entre funcionários, clientes e fornecedores. Isso inclui a tecnologia para operar as redes internas da organização, os serviços prestados por companhias telefônicas ou de telecomunicações e a tecnologia para operar sites e conectar-se com outros sistemas computacionais por meio da internet.</font><br>
                        <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Serviços:</strong>
                        <font color="black">As organizações precisam de pessoas para operar e gerenciar os outros componentes da infraestrutura de TI, além de ensinar seus funcionários a usar essas tecnologias em suas atividades. Nem mesmo as grandes organizações tem a equipe, o orçamento ou a experiência requerida para implantar e operar a ampla gama de tecnologias que necessitam. Quando precisam fazer alterações profundas em seus sistemas, ou implantar uma estrutura completamente nova, em geral, as organizações recorrem a consultores externos que as ajudam com a integração do sistema. Existem milhares de fornecedores de tecnologias que oferecem serviços e componentes da infraestrutura de TI, assim como um número igualmente grande de maneiras de combina-los.</font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    <!-- Modal Segurança-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="segu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="segurancaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                        <p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Segurança</p>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4 class="text-primary" style="text-align:center;">
                        <p>Pilares da Segurança da Informação</p>
                    </h4>
                    <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Confidencialidade:</strong>
                    <font color="black">Procedimentos e políticas que garantem as restrições do acesso a informações sensíveis aos negócios para estarem disponíveis somente para pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
                    <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Integridade:</strong>
                    <font color="black">Métodos que visam identifica se as informações não sofreram alterações durante o seu processamento ou envio.</font><br>
                    <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Disponibilidade:</strong>
                    <font color="black">Revisão do acesso á informação para garantir que estejam acessiveis sepre que solicitado por pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
                    <strong style="color:#fff;"> - Autenticidade:</strong>
                    <font color="black">É a garantia de que a informação veio da fonte anunciada, de modo que seja possível confirmar sua autoria e originalidade.</font><br><br>
                    <font color="black">A famosa frase <strong>"Se algo não pode ser feito com segurançaa, que não seja feito"</strong> também se aplica a Tecnologia ainda mais quando se trata da segurança de nossas informações que caindo em mãos erradas podem trazer prejuizos financeiros e até mesmo acidentes causados por ataques HACKERS como foi o caso recente da explosão do forno de uma indústria Alemâ que segue nosso mesmo segmento.</font>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Sistemas-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="siste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sistemasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                        <p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Sistemas</p>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Telefonia-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="tele" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="telefoniaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                        <p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Telefonia</p>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6 class="text-secondary"> A FITI, Gerência de Infra-estrutura de TI e Telefonia, área ligada á FIT (Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação), é responsável pela gestão da telefonia no âmbito da Aperam Inox América do Sul S.A.
                        Sua atuação engloba a gestão da infra-estrutura de telefonia interna (atualização, manutenção, suporte, etc.), a manutenção da malha telefônica, a manutenção das infra-estruturas de video-conferência, a gestão dos contratos de provimento de serviços de telefonia fixa, móvel e video-conferência, o processamento (recebimento, conferência, pagamento, rateio, etc.) das contas telefônicas, o reparo e suporte a aparelhos telefônicos, o estudo de novas tecnologias e a gestão dos projetos afins.</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```